# grep - filter input which contains flags (eg. %s)

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I struggle with following piece of grep filter:

```
test="$(
  grep -v "^#" "$file"           | \
  grep --word-regexp "\(,\s*\)\+google" | \
  cut -d, -f1                            | \
  tr -d "[:blank:]"
)"
```

Where `$file` is file with following content:

```
# url,keyword,optional-keyword   
https://google.com/search?q=%s,google,g    
https://github.com/,gh,github
```

The problem is that if `$file` contains a line with `%s` flag, the above grep doesn't match following line:

`https://google.com/search?q=%s,google,g`

But if I replace the flag with `%-`, the line is matched.

If the flag is a percent character followed by an alphabetical character, grep doesn't match anything.
How could I setup grep so it doesn't evaluate `%s` with special meaning?

Comment: It doesn't match for me in either case (`%-` and `%s`). What are your input and which of them you want to select?

Comment: sorry, I've edited sample input text to: google.com/search?q=%s,google,g Now it works only with "%-" flag, not with the "%s" flag. See updated question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`--word-regexp` requires that the match start at the beginning of the line or start immediately after a non-word character.

The line `https://google.com/search?q=%s,google,g` has the word `google` following a `/` and a `,` both of those are non-word characters so `grep google` will match the line.

Your pattern, however, matches `\(,\s*\)\+google` which matches the comma in the line and leaves the pattern following the `s` in `%s` and `s` is **not** a non-word character so `--word-regexp` fails the match.

If you replace `%s` with `%-` in that line then when your pattern matches the comma the immediately preceding character is the `-` from `%-` and `-` **is** a non-word character so `--word-regexp` allows the match.

tl;dr `grep` isn't handling `%s` in any special way, your pattern and arguments just don't allow it to match your input as written.